# Angular2 - routerLink after go back doesn't update url address

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I go to next page by *routerLink*

```
<a [routerLink]="['/signup']">Sign up</a>
```

And when I press Backspace or browser back button I go to previus page, but url doesn't update and remains `http://localhost:3000/signup`

When I redirect to this page programaticaly, I can go back with update url without */signup*

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I update my routing

Comment: Like the versions?